# PHP Populating an Array from a MySql Query

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to create an array of data to be pass to another function that is populated from a database query and am not sure how to do this.

```
$dataArray[0][1];

$qry = mysql_query("SELECT Id, name FROM users");

while($res = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
    $dataArray[$res['Id']][$res['name']]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I spent about thirty seconds trying to understand how this code shows PHP polluting an array.

Comment: @bipedalShark: yeah that was kind of funny!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would look better

```
$dataArray = array();

$qry = mysql_query("SELECT Id, name FROM users");

while($res = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
    $dataArray[$res['Id']] = $res['name'];
}
```

you can take a look at the PHP [manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) how to declare and manipulate arrays.

Answer (score 3):

***The below code sniper is very handy...***

$select=" WRITE YOUR SELECT QUERY ";
    $queryResult= mysql_query($select);

```
//DECLARE YOUR ARRAY WHERE YOU WILL KEEP YOUR RECORD SETS
$data_array=array();

//STORE ALL THE RECORD SETS IN THAT ARRAY 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryResult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
    array_push($data_array,$row);
}


mysql_free_result($queryResult);


//TEST TO SEE THE RESULT OF THE ARRAY 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Thanks

Comment: This is excellent. The minimalist and most efficient answer in my honest opinion.